# Haskell : Comparing if two binary trees have the same elements

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

So I am working on a function that detects if two binary trees have the same numbers in them.

So what I've come up with is the following which works just fine but the problem is that I am using total of 5 functions. Is there another way of detecting if two BT's have the same elements with just one function ? Here is my solution so far which seems to work just fine.

```
flatten :: BinTree a -> [a]
flatten Empty        = []
flatten (Node l x r) = flatten l ++ [x] ++ flatten r

splt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splt 0 xs = ([], xs)
splt _ [] = ([],[])
splt n (x:xs) = (\ys-> (x:fst ys, snd ys)) (splt (n-1) xs)

merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] 
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys    
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (x > y) then y:merge (x:xs) ys else x:merge xs(y:ys)

msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort [] =[]
msort (x:[]) = (x:[])
msort xs = (\y -> merge (msort (fst y)) (msort (snd y))) (splt (length xs `div` 2) xs)

areTreesEqual :: (Ord a) => BinTree a -> BinTree a-> Bool
areTreesEqual Empty Empty = True
areTreesEqual Empty a = False
areTreesEqual a Empty = False
areTreesEqual a b = msort (flatten (a) ) == msort (flatten (b))
```

Comment: Why do you need to define your own merge-sort function, instead of using `Data.List.sort`(`By`)? That would save 3 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
import Data.MultiSet as Set

equal a b = accum a == accum b
  where accum Empty = Set.empty
        accum (Node l x r) = Set.insert x (accum l `Set.union` accum r)
```

Sets are lovely for unordered comparison and multisets will make sure that

```
 1   /=   1
1 1
```

Eg, that duplicate numbers are counted properly. If this isn't a big concern, than swap `MultiSet` for `Set`. I think 3 lines is pretty decent for this sort of thing.